# angular way to change image src?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<div class="float-right">

  <span class="language dashboard" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img class="current" src="us-flag.png" />
  </span>

  <div class="dropdown dashboard">
    <a href="javascript:" (click)="setch('en');" class="dropdown-item">
      <img src="us-flag.png" alt="" />english </a
    >
    <a href="javascript:" (click)="setch('it');" class="dropdown-item">
      <img src="it-flag.png" alt="" />italian </a
    >
  </div>

</div>
```

this the jquery way:

```
$('.dropdown-item').on({
    'click': function(){
    //do other thing
        $('.current').attr('src','it-flag.png');
    }
});
```

am using angular 6
looking to write it in angular way without using jquery, however not familiar with it..

looking to load the logic at

```
  ngOnInit() {

     //assign from default database language setting
     var dbflag = "it";
     //assign $('.current').attr('src','it-flag.png');

  }

  setch(){
    //change flag class="current"
 }
```

any idea guys, for writing it in angular ts way?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this on Html :

```
<div class="float-right">

  <span class="language dashboard" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img class="current" src={{flag}} />
  </span>

  <div class="dropdown dashboard">
    <a href="javascript:" (click)="setch('en');" class="dropdown-item">
      <img src="us-flag.png" alt="" />english </a
    >
    <a href="javascript:" (click)="setch('it');" class="dropdown-item">
      <img src="it-flag.png" alt="" />italian </a
    >
  </div>

</div>
```

on ts file declare a new variable and assign img name on it:

```
 flag :string;

  setch(fl){   
    if (fl == 'it') {
      this.flag = 'it-flag.png"'
    } else {
      this.flag = 'us-flag.png'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do using angular binding.Change `src` to `[src]`

```
<div class="float-right">

  <div class="dropdown dashboard">      
    <a href="javascript:" (click)="setch('it');" class="dropdown-item">
      <img [src]="displayedImage" alt="">italian </a
    >
  </div>

</div>
```

in `component.ts` , you need to declare a variable called `displayedImage`.

```
this.displayedImage='it-flag.png';
```

Comment: supposed to work , just check console if any error have